# Prettier, prefer single line objects as arguments resulting in single line functions

Tags: javascript, prettier

[Playground link](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEAzAFMABAHSlrOAJySwEYBfAGi2zwIENSAmCgShCpAgAcYBLaAGdkoBkSIQA7gAVxCESgYAbKQwCeIrgCMiDMAGs4MAMo99-KAHNkMIgFc4XOAFttcACYfPAGQbX7Bis4ADEIIhcGGAFrZBAGexgIThAACxgXZQB1VP54IXMwOBMFPP4ANzz1OLAhLRBLIWIYGT0rSORUFSauACshAA8AIT1DYxMGFzgfSzhO7qcQfoGTSytlOABFewh4eeUekHMiJqI47QZ3ZRSeIksYLP4PGFTkAA4ABi5biCasvR4cVucFO5TmXAAjjt4K1eIp4kIALRQOCeTwpIhwKH8TGtIIdJBdA6LJoufi2BwktYbba7OaEhZcGCXR7PV5IZhMvT8ZRrADCEBcBJAIIArCl7E0ACqXRREw7lRwASSg3lgJjAdz4AEFVSYYOoNvsmhQKEA)

Input

```
f({
  er: 1}, {
  a: 2})
```

Actual Output

```
f(
  {
    er: 1,
  },
  {
    a: 2,
  }
);
```

Expected output

```
f({ er: 1 }, { a: 2 })
```

Note, the one liner code is not exceeding the line length limit.

Anyway to tune prettier to format as expected?

Comment: Prettier can't return in single line format, because it's an uglier format.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar experience with Prettier. If you "hint" to Prettier that you want your object to be multi-line, Prettier auto expands to a more beautiful multi-line as in your example. However, if you wrote `f({er: 1}, { a: 2})` (single line) in the first place, Prettier also seems to accept this. AFAIK, this behavior is [in the core logic/rationale of Prettier](https://prettier.io/docs/en/rationale.html#multi-line-objects) and I have not found ways to circumvent this behavior.

Also note that this behavior seems to apply only to object. So, if you keep your **opening bracket** and the object content on one-line, Prettier defaults to one-line. Example:

```js
f(
  { er: 1
  }, 
  { a: 2
  }
)

// Or this
f({  er: 1
  }
  ,
  {  a: 2    
             }
 )

// Both will result in one-line expression
f({ er: 1 }, { a: 2 });
```